# Join column values from one table to rows in new column on another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to write a SQL query in SQL Server 2008 that will match the column values from a single query into a new column on a table where the column headers are stored as row values.

I have two queries:

| KEY | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| COL01 | 25 |
| COL02 | 71 |
| COL03 | 13 |

The same row values listed under the KEY column from table 1 are the column names for table 2.

| COL01 | COL02 | COL03 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| XX | YY | ZZ |

Desired result:

| KEY | VALUE | NEW_COL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| COL01 | 25 | XX |
| COL02 | 71 | YY |
| COL03 | 13 | ZZ |

Comment: Why are you using unsupported software?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . I would suggest unpivoting and joining:

```
select t1.*, t2.val
from table2 t2 cross join
     (values (t2.col01, 'col01'), (t2.col02, 'col02'), (t2.col03, 'col03')
     ) v(val, which) join
     table1 t1
     on t2.which = t1.key;
```